# Difficulties to make another route expressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, ejs

I am doing a site as of my studies.
The technology being free, I decided to code with nodejs/Express.
For my first route `/home`, everything went well. But I can't create others.

[image: error message]

Yet I thought I understood the system well.
It would bother me if it was due to a silly error because I have been on this problem for too long .

`index.js` :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4242;

app.use('/', require('./routes/home_route'));
app.use('/auther', require('./routes/auther_route')); //the problem     
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`localhost:${PORT}`);
});

app.use('/styles', express.static(__dirname + '/styles'));
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/scripts'));
app.use('/pictures', express.static(__dirname + '/pictures'));
```

`home_route.js` :

```
const express = require('express');
const { homeView } = require('../controllers/home_controller');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/home', homeView);
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.redirect('./home'));
module.exports = router;
```

`home_controller.js` :

```
let page = 'home_view.ejs';

const homeView = (req, res) => {
    res.render("constant_view.ejs", { page : page });
}
module.exports =  { homeView };
```

`constant_view.ejs` :

```
html...
<%= page %>
html...
```

And all this is very good.
And now this is what does not work .

`auther_route.js` :

```
const express = require('express');
const { autherView } = require('../controllers/auther_controller');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/auther', autherView);
module.exports = router;
```

`auther_controller.js` :

```
let page = 'auter_view.ejs';

const autherView = (req, res) => {
    res.render("constant_view", { page : page });
}
module.exports =  { autherView };
```

Thank you in advance for your time and your answers.

Comment: in auther_route.js the get method is /auther but in you index.js you specify /auther for the principal url, try with: auther/auther

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to reach the route `/auther` in index.js, but inside `auther_route` you create a route with `/auther` as well. So in index.js you should add `/auther/auther` or just change to `app.use('/', require('./routes/auther_route'))`;

Regards